# iOS/Swift: How to get dynamic deep links that survive the install from app store WITH parameters by configuring only one link on console Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

When the app is not installed, and the user open the dynamic link, the app store is well opened, but once installed, if I click on "open", it open the apps, it says a message "link paste from the navigator", but the dynamic link is only launched without the parameters

> func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity:
> NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping
> ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

Here is the function:

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
          let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()
            .handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { dynamiclink, error in
              // ...
                print(dynamiclink!)
                
                let urlStr: String = (dynamiclink?.url?.absoluteString.lowercased())!
                //  UserDefaults.standard.set(urlStr, forKey: "url")
                
                if (urlStr.contains("test?code=azerty")) {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(urlStr, forKey: "url")
                    
                    let str: String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "url") as! String
                    if (str.contains("test?code=azerty"))
                       {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "test", message: str, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:  .default, handler: { action in
                            switch action.style{
                            case .default:
                                print("default")
                                
                            case .cancel:
                                print("cancel")
                                
                            case .destructive:
                                print("destructive")
                                
                            }}))
                        
                        let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                        let activeViewCont = navigationController.visibleViewController
                        activeViewCont?.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                        //activeViewCont!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0, execute: {
                            activeViewCont!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        })
                       
                       }
                }
                
            }
    
          return handled
        }
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print(url)
        print("handleOpenURL")
        
        //let urlStr: String = url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "colas://", with: "")
        let urlStr: String = url.absoluteString.lowercased()
        //  UserDefaults.standard.set(urlStr, forKey: "url")
        
        if (urlStr.contains("test?code=azerty")) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(urlStr, forKey: "url")
            
            let str: String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "url") as! String
            if (str.contains("test?code=azerty"))
               {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "test", message: str, preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:  .default, handler: { action in
                    switch action.style{
                    case .default:
                        print("default")
                        
                    case .cancel:
                        print("cancel")
                        
                    case .destructive:
                        print("destructive")
                        
                    }}))
                
                let navigationController = app.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                let activeViewCont = navigationController.visibleViewController
                activeViewCont?.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                //activeViewCont!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0, execute: {
                activeViewCont!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
               }
        }


        return true
    }
```

Info plist:

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://myapp.page.link</string>
    </array>
```

Domains in app:
[image: domainsInApp]

Domains on website:
[image: domainsOnSite]

FireBase option:

[image]
[image]

Scheme:
[image]

How can I get the function fired, just after install the application from the app store, with the dynamic link containing the parameters?

Message:

```
xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.myapp://google/link/?deep_link_id=https://myapp.page.link/&match_type=unique&utm_medium=dynamic_link&request_ip_version=IP_V4&utm_source=firebase&match_message=Link is uniquely matched for this device.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two problems were :
1/ the good writing of the dynamical url :

```
https://yourapp.page.link/?link=https://yourapp.com/test=12345&isi=14602xxxxx&ibi=com.xxxx.yourapp
```

This is the good way to create the url

2/ The parameter in info.plist in Xcode is important :

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://yourapp.com/link</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: But why do you put https://yourapp.com/link ? what is for "link" ?

Comment: In all case, it works :) thanks

Comment: is it possible to achieve this in native approach without using any third party SDK?